# Select nested JSON value from array

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, youtube, getjson

Consider this getJSON request which pulls channel detail from youtube for `thebeatles`:

```
var youtubeFEED = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=thebeatles&key={{ google_api_key }}"

$.getJSON(youtubeFEED, function(data){
    console.log('data loaded');
});
```

This results in:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/8SEUwKelrqHehoM7_2t5MWZY3T8\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/Il2dF5SRdky6_tqanN3hNuDyfxc\"",
   "id": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "111395306401981598462"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I select the value of `uploads` (`UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw` in this case), and store it as a variable?

As an example, when I try:

`console.log(data.items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);`

I get :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'relatedPlaylists' of undefined`.

**Bonus points**: My aim is actually to produce a list of all uploaded videoIds for a given username. Is there any way to do this without the uploads playlistID? [This](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&_h=12&) is the only method I have found.

Comment: `data.items` is an array, so: `data.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`

Comment: May be there more items?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto not in this case, this is everyone the youtube API returns